# Ton vs Klang vs Geräusch for sounds electronic and electrical devices make?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference, single-word-request, colloquial

Especially for unseen mechanism. Examples:

- a ventilator on the wall stops working and doesn't make any sound anymore
- a hard drive inside the laptop is failing and making screeching noise

In both cases, I can only tell there is a problem from the noise or lack thereof.

And would you use plural in the context? For example Töne vs Ton, or Geräusche vs Geräusch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither *Ton* nor *Klang* would be my first choice, since their musical connotation is strong; especially *Ton* implies a pitch to be measured in *hertz* which does not apply here.

*Geräusch* is fine, as in:

> Die Festplatte macht seltsame Geräusche.

The plural is appropriate here, because the produced noise is likely to be changing all the times. *Betriebsgeräusch* is the technical term for the standard sound a device produces.

Comment: For the ventilator it would be "Der Ventilator macht kein Geräusch mehr" or simply "Man kann den Ventilator nicht mehr hören."

Comment: For the hard drive you can also use the singular, assuming that there is a specific noise, like a screeching of constant pitch.

Comment: You can however use verbs for "Ton" and "Klang" (there is no corresponding one for "Geräusch"): "*Die Festplatte klingt merkwürdig*", "*Es tönt komisch aus meinem Laptop*". For something that doesn't make a sound any more, a colloquial expression is "*Der Ventilator macht keinen Mucks[er] mehr*".

Comment: @Bergi “es tönt” is a bit silly pseudo-poetic though. “Es ertönen gar merkwürdige Laute aus meinem Laptop”...